# FLUTTER Sign-up/Sign-in with Google popup not appearing

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, popup, google-signin

I want to make the user login to the app with google but the pop-up is not coming on the screen. What do I do to make the pop-up appear? When I press on the "Continue with Google" button, it does nothing.

When I debug my code, the debugger straight up goes to the last print statement -

```
 print("GOOGLE SIGN IN: ${googleSignIn.clientId}");
```

here is my code-

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

part 'google_sign_in_event.dart';
part 'google_sign_in_state.dart';

class GoogleSignInBloc extends Bloc<GoogleSignInEvent, GoogleSignInState> {
  GoogleSignInBloc() : super(GoogleSignInInitial()) {
    on<GoogleLogInEvent>((event, emit) {
      GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
      GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
      // GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;
      //final googlelogin = MeditationGoogleSignIn().googleLogIn();

      Future googleLogIn() async {
        try {
          final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();

          if (googleUser == null) {
            print("NO GOOGLE USER");
            return null;
          }
          _user = googleUser;

          final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
          final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
            idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
          );
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
        } catch (e) {
          print("THERE IS AN ERROR IN LOGIN: ${e.toString()}");
        }
      }

      print("GOOGLE SIGN IN: ${googleSignIn.clientId}");
    });

    on<GoogleLogOutEvent>((event, emit) {
      Future googleLogOut() async {
        final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
        await googleSignIn.disconnect();
        FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: try to remove if (googleUser == null) {
            print("NO GOOGLE USER");
            return null;
          } and then run the code

Comment: I did, it is still not doing anything.

Comment: Have you configured SHA certificate fingerprints in firebase..?

Comment: yes, I have, I have added both the SHA fingerprints

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to make the Google Sign-In pop-up appear on the web:

1. Use the Firebase method: This will ensure that the user is prompted
   to select an account from their Google account list. To do this, add
   the following code to your signInWithPopup() method:

```dart
if (kIsWeb) {
  final GoogleAuthProvider provider = GoogleAuthProvider()
      .setCustomParameters({'prompt': 'select_account'});
  await _firebaseAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
}
```

2. Use the native Google Sign-In button:it will require you to modify
   your UI to use the native button. To do this, you will need to add
   the Google Sign-In web to your project and follow the instructions
   in the documentation to implement the button.

```dart
class loginGoogleButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const loginGoogleButton({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<loginGoogleButton> createState() => _loginGoogleButtonState();
}

class _loginGoogleButtonState extends State<loginGoogleButton> {
  GoogleSignInAccount? user;

  GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    clientId: const String.fromEnvironment('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
      setState(() {
        user = account;
        
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final body = ElevatedButtonLab.normal(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      child: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 12, bottom: 12, left: 12),
        child: (GoogleSignInPlatform.instance as web.GoogleSignInPlugin)
            .renderButton(),
      ),
    );

    return body;
  }
}
```

Note: The second option is more complex and requires you to modify your UI and check your imports if is a mobile too. However, it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try add scopes: `GoogleSignIn(scopes: ['email', 'profile'])`

Comment: I had to add ```CFBundleURLSchemes``` to my info.plist and the issue was resolved. Thank you for suggestion!